# Align ':after plus/minus sign' Centrally Within Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using an Accordion which is built of buttons, I've got the 'plus' and 'minus' signs as ':after'

So far I've tried 'justify-content: center' within the button, I've also tried 'vertical-align: middle', neither had any effect and when I tried to wrap a div around the button to implement the styling on that button, it stopped the accordion from working.

I also am having trouble when on a thin screen the plus sign is coming into the text, it's currently floating to the right but there is no designated space between them to stop a crossover.

All the code I've tried to use to centrally align this element i haven't got to work, please see below:

[image]

Here is the code:]

**HTML:**

```
      <button class="accordion">Where is your company located?</button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2">We are located in the heart of San Francisco, California USA! We do have shipping warehouses located in the USA, Europe, and Asia to ensure the quickest delivery for your location.</p>
</div>
  
  <button class="accordion">What is the warranty and return policy?</button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2"><span>We have a Risk-Free Policy. During this promotion - you can try the product for 30 days - if you decide for whatever reason this is not for you then you can return the device for a full refund.</span></p>
</div>
  
  <button class="accordion">Does the product have a specific method of operation? Is it easy to use?</button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2">Yes! It is very simple and easy to use. You will receive a detailed user manual with positions and pointers to maximize your results. :)</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion {
  background-color: white;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #262626;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

The javascript, incase it helps at all:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks if you can help.

Dale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you. I added an `<span>` due to control both parts and then `display: flex;`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: red;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  border: 0;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 18px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


.accordion span:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  color: #262626;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.accordion.active span:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
      <button class="accordion">Where is your company located? <span></span></button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2">We are located in the heart of San Francisco, California USA! We do have shipping warehouses located in the USA, Europe, and Asia to ensure the quickest delivery for your location.</p>
</div>
  
  <button class="accordion">What is the warranty and return policy?<span></span></button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2"><span>We have a Risk-Free Policy. During this promotion - you can try the product for 30 days - if you decide for whatever reason this is not for you then you can return the device for a full refund.</span></p>
</div>
  
  <button class="accordion">Does the product have a specific method of operation? Is it easy to use?<span></span></button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="zpa-regular2">Yes! It is very simple and easy to use. You will receive a detailed user manual with positions and pointers to maximize your results. :)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant Alberto, Thanks so much. Do you have an explanation of why adding the span made it work? is it because the 'plus/minus' is now assigned to an element, which can now be centered within the button?

Comment: You can do it with no `<span>` but having two elements it's pretty easy with `display: flex` to align and keep the elements separated (to avoid overlapping)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the practical behavior of concerned css properties to achieve vertical align of minus sign and plus sign inside button(I haven't tried for other elements like span or div but I believe it works the same, if not pardon my guess) upon increasing the font-size(to any extent) regardless of font-family used.

**Consider this an alternative to what has already been answered by Alberto Rhuetras.**

**Use Case:** Sometimes you want bigger buttons with a plus or minus sign inside it. But the font-size is too small for the button. As you increase the font-size of the button, the plus and minus sign fails to align vertically as was the case with me. That's when I came up with the following solution.

**Note:** I could't find a solution anywhere else, so I ended up with this solution. I am open to any say you have on the solution so feel free to leave some comments:)

```css
/* common style */
.minus, .plus {
   height: 50px;
   width: 200px;
   background: #216AFF;
   color: white;
}

.minus {
  font-size: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.plus {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.demo {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
}

.demo::after {
  content: "\02795";
  font-size: 18px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 23px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<button class="minus">-</button>
<br>
<button class="plus">+</button>
<br>
<button class="demo">Does the product have a specific method of operation? Is it easy to use? What is the warranty and return policy?</button>
```

Use display-flex on the button and use the value of line-height to position the plus or minus sign vertically within the button. Increase in line-height value moves the signs downward and and decrease in line-height value moves the signs upward. Thanks!